# SQL Server - Count each objects at instance level

Tags: sql-server

We want to get total count of each object type at the SQL Server instance level (including all databases).

E.g.

```
Stored Procedures
Views
Tables
Constraints
Jobs
Linked Servers
Replication
```

This code returns the counts at the database level; how to change this code to show the counts at the **instance** level?

```
WITH objs AS
(
    SELECT 
        type_desc AS Object_Type,
        COUNT(*) AS Object_Count, 1 AS JoinColumn
    FROM 
        sys.objects
    --exclude internal tables, service queues, and system tables
    WHERE 
        TYPE NOT IN ('IT', 'S', 'SQ')
    GROUP BY 
        type_desc
),
tots AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Type_Count, 1 AS JoinColumn
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE TYPE NOT IN ('IT', 'S', 'SQ')
)
SELECT 
    Object_Type, Object_Count, Type_Count,
    CAST((Object_Count * 1.0) / Type_Count * 100 AS INT) AS Type_Pct
FROM objs o
JOIN tots s ON o.JoinColumn = s.JoinColumn
ORDER BY Object_Type;
```

Regards

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL and iterate over all databases on the server. Do you want to include system databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's and example that uses dynamic SQL and a cursor to iterate over all user-databases on the server.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @DatabaseCounts TABLE(
       Object_Type nvarchar(60)
     , Object_Count INT
     );

DECLARE
      @DatabaseName sysname
    , @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

DECLARE Databases CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT name 
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE
        name NOT IN(N'master',N'model',N'tempdb',N'msdb',N'SSISDB',N'distribution');

OPEN Databases;
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM Databases INTO @DatabaseName;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;
    SET @SQL = N'
USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N';
    SELECT
          type_desc AS Object_Type
        , COUNT(*) AS Object_Count
    FROM sys.objects
    --exclude internal tables, service queues, and system tables
    WHERE TYPE NOT IN (''IT'', ''S'', ''SQ'')
    GROUP BY type_desc
';
    INSERT INTO @DatabaseCounts
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
END;
CLOSE Databases;
DEALLOCATE Databases;

WITH
     instance_counts1 AS (
        SELECT
              Object_Type
            , SUM(Object_Count) AS Object_Count
        FROM @DatabaseCounts
        GROUP BY Object_Type
    )
    , instance_counts2 AS (
        SELECT
              Object_Type
            , Object_Count
            , (SELECT SUM(Object_Count) FROM instance_counts1) AS Type_Count
        FROM instance_counts1
    )
SELECT
      Object_Type
    , Object_Count
    , Type_Count
    , CAST(ROUND(Object_Count * 100.0 / Type_Count, 0) AS INT) AS Type_Pct
FROM instance_counts2;
```